# Checkstyle ConstantName rule kicks in for things that are not really constant

Tags: java, checkstyle

I would like to check that my field names are uppercase only for fields that meet my preferred definition of "constant", as stated in [Google's Java Coding Guidelines](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.4-constant-names).

Thus:

```
private static final integer NUM = 1974;  // is a constant
private static final String NAME = "Freddie"  // is a constant

private static final Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();  // is NOT a constant
private static final Logger myLogger = LogManager.getLogger();  // is NOT a constant
```

Is it possible to specify a rule that requires uppercase naming only if the type is a primitive type or a final reference to a String or other *immutable* class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.  Checkstyle would have to execute the code.  For instance, `private static final Map<String, String> myMap = Map.of("One", "Blue", "Two", "Red");` is an immutable value.

One thing you can do is tell Checkstyle that it should not enforce the naming scheme on private fields:

```
<module name="ConstantName">
    <property name="applyToPrivate" value="false"/>
</module>
```

Another option is to specify the permitted names:

```
<module name="ConstantName">
    <property name="format"
        value="^([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*|myMap|myLogger)$"/>
</module>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's probably the best we can do for now. I'll wait and see if there are any other answers before accepting yours. It would have been nice if checkstyle at least recognised some well-known immutable classes and treated those as constant and did not apply the rule when it wasn't certain whether a class was immutable. Especially given the definition of "constant" by Google Coding Guidelines and many other popular guidelines.